# Nodejs fork from child_process and main master

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 files:
- master.js
- children_1.js
- children_1_1.js

master.js contain:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var children_1 = fork('children_1.js');
```

children_1.js contain:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var children_1_1 = fork('children_1_1.js');
```

children_1_1.js:

```
process.send({hello: 'world'});
```

But this message come into children_1.js. How can i send message from children_1_1.js to master.js? Is it possible in node.js standart complectation?

Answer (score 0):

you have to forward this message in children_1.js when you fork, you create a new process, and node.js establisch an ipc channel between the forking and the forked process. nothing more